# How to set Laravel Passport Token Expire Time when Remember me check box checked

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Respected Sir/Ma'am, when i checked Remember_me checkbox then that time token will expire after 1 minutes.

```
 if ($request->remember_me) {
               $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(1);
            }
```

The above code not work. The token doesn't expire. I will access the below route after 1 min, I want to block access of **AuthController@checkAuthWorkingOrNot** after 1 min when the token time expires.

```
    Route::get('demo', 'AuthController@checkAuthWorkingOrNot')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Please Sir/Ma'am help me, I am new in laravel

Answer (score 2):

In your LogIn Controller Add below code in same order.

```
            if ($request->remember_me) {
                Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes(3));
            }
            $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
            $token = $tokenResult->token;
```